# Allure Framework Graph's not showing

Tags: python, graph, report, allure, python-behave

I am trying to fill up my allure reports with the graphs but only the defaults are being shown (Severity and Duration).

I looked at the allure-reports/widgets, and the json files are there but it still not showing on the webpage.

[graph for categories trend missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80TJj.png)

btw, the Trend section on the Overview is empty as well.

I am using allure 2.5.0 with python-behave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All TREND graphs works either with CI or if you took care of transfering history.json file to a new report build.

In other words - there are two files under ..\allure-report\history folder, called history.json and history-trend.json, that are created first time you build a report. 
In order to make it work w/o CI you should copy these files from your PREVIOUS report to allure-results folder BEFORE you build a next one.

Comment: this is my interpretation of your answer:
copy `history.json` and `history-trend.json` from 
/tmp/2582868701970402783/allure-report/history

to /path/to/dir/webpagebuilder/{reports}
and execute `allure serve /path/to/dir/webpagebuilder/{reports}`

is this correct? it didnt fix it :( the trend json files is not empty either, i dont understand why its not being applied as a graph whereas duration.json and severity.json are. https://i.stack.imgur.com/80TJj.png

Comment: I found a way to populate it! by copying the history folder itself and not only the 2 json files :)